# error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to build my project:

```
Angle.cpp:466: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in '(+out)-
>std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::operator<< [with _Elem = char, 
_Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((const Angle*)this)->Angle::getDegrees())
<< "\37777777660"'
```

I've done some research on it and it looks like I have a wrong method header, but I'm new to cpp and don't know how to fix this error.

Here's the .h:

```
#include "OutputOps.h"
// End user added include file section

#include <vxWorks.h>
#include <ostream>
class Angle {

public:
// Default constructor/destructor
~Angle();

// User-defined methods
//
// Default Constructor sets Angle to 0.
Angle();
...
// Returns the value of this Angle in degrees.
double getDegrees() const;
....
// Prints the angle to the output stream as "x°" in degrees
void output(std::ostream& out) const;

...
private:
...
double radians;
static const double DEGREES_PER_RADIAN /* = 180.0 / PI */;    
};

#endif // ANGLE_H
```

And here's the method:

```
#include "MathUtility.h"
#include <cmath>
// End user added include file section

#ifndef Angle_H
#include "Angle.h"
#endif

//
// Prints the angle to the output stream as "x°" in degrees
void Angle::output(std::ostream& out) const
{
    out << getDegrees() << "°";
}
//
// Returns the value of this Angle in degrees.
double Angle::getDegrees() const
{
return radians * DEGREES_PER_RADIAN;
}
```

Comment: Show the headers you're including, also.

Comment: What does your function **getDegrees()** return?

Comment: I added the code for the getDegrees and headers.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the problem lies with the degree sign, which isn't an ascii character.

Try instead:

```
wcout <<  getDegrees() << L"\u00B0";
```

Comment: I tested your code, just by simply replacing the string with "hello" and it still gave back the same error.

Comment: @iSelkiies include <iostream> and <string> please.

Comment: Or simply `"\xB0"`.  (The degree sign is the only thing I can see, too, but even then, the type of `"..."` should always be `char const[]`, or else the compiler should complain about it.)

Comment: Same error. I split up the lines into 'out << getDegrees() and out << "Hello". However now I have a whole bunch of errors about ostream. I'm thinking there's something completely else wrong with it.

Comment: @iSelkiies post code that replicates the problem on ideone.com.